# How to use certificate-transparency library?

Tags: certificate, python, certificate-transparency

[The Python library for searching certificate logs](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency/tree/master/python) has very little documentation. How is it possible to use it to search the logs and retrieve something intelligible?

The closest I can find is just to run [dashboard.py](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency/blob/master/python/ct/dashboard/dashboard.py) or [simple_scan.py](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency/blob/master/python/ct/client/tools/simple_scan.py), but simple_scan.py throws this error:

```
  File "/certificate-transparency/python/ct/client/tools/simple_scan.py", line 35, in run
    if not FLAGS.output:
NameError: global name 'FLAGS' is not defined
```

This makes no sense since FLAGS is part of gflags and gflags is imported in the script.

dashboard.py throws this error:

```
  File "/certificate-transparency/python/ct/dashboard/dashboard.py", line 141, in <module>
    with open(FLAGS.ctlog_config, "r") as config:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ct/config/logs.config'
```

`ct/config/logs.config` definitely exists. I assume it's a PYTHONPATH issue, but `ct`'s parent directory, `python`, is in the PYTHONPATH.

Ideally I wouldn't use this library as scripts anyway but as a library. I suppose I could just basically cut and paste what I need from the scripts, but it's not clear what I need for the scripts to function since the scripts don't function at all!

I see absolutely no guidance as to how to handle this thing. As another example, I sense that I could use something like this [async_client](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency/blob/master/python/ct/client/tools/async_client_example.py), but it's not at all clear what exactly it's doing beyond fetching an sth and running as a server in some way.

Any ideas? How am I supposed to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer to a similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/certificate-transparency/edLMtFSX8k8/c4FNMQ48BgAJ), the library doesn't really do what I thought it did, i.e. query logs. For that, I apparently have to query a log "monitor."

Answer (score 0):

If you set the variable PYTHONPATH to the python folder you could start using it.

`export PYTHONPATH=/path-to-repo/certificate-transparency/python`

The output flag can be set by starting the command in this way:

```
./ct/client/tools/simple_scan.py --output /tmp/pct
```